# CameraX recorded video analysis graphics error

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception, android-camerax

Android `CameraX`, prompt when `VideoCapture` and `ImageAnalysis` are used at the same time:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No supported surface combination is found for camera device-Id: 1. May be attempting to bind too many use cases. Existing surfaces: [] New configs: [androidx.camera.core.impl.ImageAnalysisConfig@7ea65ca , androidx.camera.core.impl.VideoCaptureConfig@e0d133b, androidx.camera.core.impl.PreviewConfig@20f5a58]

Answer (score 1):

CameraX does not support this combination for most of the devices.
Here you can find the supported combinations: [Source](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture#combine-use-cases)

Notice that video capture use case is not even in supported combinations. However, as far as I know, CameraX team is working on this.

For now, I would suggest you to use Camera2 Api. [Here](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) is a very well documented library that would allow you to do what you want to achieve.